# How can I stretch with position absolute but remain below another item?

Tags: html, css

Essentially what I want to accomplish is:

```
+---------------------+
|+-------------------+|
||      topbar       ||
|+-------------------+|
||                   ||
||     expanding     ||
||                   ||
|+-------------------+|
+---------------------+
```

With a few constraints:

1. topbar can resize itself (with javascript) but is always a fixed height + width
2. expanding must fill the rest of the space regardless of the size of its content
3. any item positioned absolutely in expanding must be relative to the bottom left corner of topbar
4. the size of expanding must not be set with javascript (i.e. purely css)
5. I wish to enlarge the height of .topbar without needing to also manually/programmatically adjust the height of .expanding. I.e. the .expanding div should auto-adjust.

I tried:

```
.topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
.expanding {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

but then it couples the height of topbar with expanding and I dont want to do that if I dont have to.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s2wq48np/

Comment: do you have some HTML that we can work with? It's kind of difficult to know what else is going on in page. (i.e.: are those the only two divs within the body? Or is it just one part of a page?)

Comment: @leftside I added a fiddle for you

Comment: do you mean that the height of `.topbar` will be increasing and decreasing?

Comment: ***Op wishes to enlarge the height of `.topbar` without needing to also manually/programmatically adjust the height of `.expanding`. The need is for the .expanding div to auto-adjust.*** *(from comments below a deleted answer - mine - that was incorrect)*